# Disable form security CakePHP

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

Is it possible to turn of all CakePHP security features for only 1 particular form in a view? So I don't get any hidden fields (tokens) in that form.

Thank you,

Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable it for that action via:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    if ($this->request->params['action'] == 'action') { 
        $this->Security->validatePost = false; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove annoying hidden inputs `_Token.key` and `fields` from your form (for instance, to clarify query string when you use `GET` method), you need to do following stuff on `beforeRender` in addition to `beforeFilter` from [*tigrang*'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004812/301663):

```
function beforeRender() {
    parent::beforeRender();
    unset($this->params["_Token"]);
}
```

(This is actual at least for CakePHP 1.3)